# Security tags on library book interfere with phone operation

Tags: hardware

I've just noticed that the security tag that's usually found on books from library is somehow the cause to my phone (HTC M9) sending out notification sounds incessantly when it's nearby. Google searches lead me nowhere so I'm asking the question here. I'm assuming it's because of magnet. Has anyone else noticed this and how do I solve this sort of problem? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

After trying out other related searches, I've discovered that turning off NFC (Settings > Wireless & networks > More) will solve this particular problem.